# Generate 3 years

Tags: sql, oracle

Tying to generate 3 years of data as below

```
31-DEC-17
31-DEC-18
31-DEC-19
```

below query generates 3 months. How do i transfer this to 3 years

```
select LAST_DAY(add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1)) as mth 
        from dual 
        connect by level <= 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiply parameter by 12:

```
select last_day(add_months(date '2017-01-01', (level - 1) * 12 )) as mth 
  from dual 
  connect by level <= 3
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1b3f4a1a33abd025aa9866451d9c7202)</sup>**

Comment: Quick question just to add to this.. how do we fetch last date from a year ?  LAST_DAY(extract(year from sysdate))??

Comment: The last day of the year is fixed. So `'31-DEC-'||extract(year from sysdate)` would do it (depending on your NLS date settings.

Comment: @APC makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. How do i change this to only display year Part like 2017, 2018, 2019. Tried extract(year from '2017-01-01') but doesn't seem working

Comment: You can use `extract` or `to_char` like in this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=30fdd1fffb1bf97a5b8f59e04bf47be7).

Answer (score 1):

use <=36 which will generate  till 31-DEC-19

```
    select LAST_DAY(add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1)) as mth 
        from dual 
        connect by level <= 36
```

Comment: Thank you . But i want only Last day of the calendar year.. If I keep <=36 it repeats every months. I just want last  day for each year.. like this 31-DEC-17 31-DEC-18 31-DEC-19

Answer (score 0):

*As @APC mentions, last_day function depends on your NLS Date Settings. So, you may prefer `truncate` function truncated to the unit specified by `yyyy` as below instead :*

```
select add_months(trunc(date'2017-01-01','yyyy'), level * 12 ) - 1
       as "Last Days"
  from dual 
connect by level <= 3;

Last Days
----------
2017-12-31
2018-12-31
2019-12-31
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/HNRALY86876)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. How do i change this to only display year Part like 2017, 2018, 2019. Tried  extract(year from '2017-01-01')  but doesn't seem working

Comment: @sunnybabau you're welcome. you can try : `extract ( year from add_months(trunc(date'2017-01-01','yyyy'), level * 12 ) - 1 )` **OR** `to_char ( add_months(trunc(date'2017-01-01','yyyy'), level * 12 ) - 1, 'yyyy' )` to get `2017, 2018, 2019`. Since `add_months(trunc(date'2017-01-01','yyyy'), level * 12 ) - 1` returns `date` type value.

Comment: @sunnybabau For your case, you need to convert to `extract(year from date'2017-01-01')`. Since only `'2017-01-01'` is just a string.